# Is there anyway to get a background image to be fixed at first and then scroll?

Tags: html, css

So I am basically trying to get a scrolling parallax effect with multiple background images on my webpage. I will post a link to a website with a perfect example of what I am talking about (look at the first two background images on the webpage). Here is that link: https://www.wix.com/website-template/view/html/1885?originUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wix.com%2Fwebsite%2Ftemplates%2Fhtml%2Fportfolio-cv%2F1&bookName=&galleryDocIndex=0&category=portfolio-cv
The problem with my webpage however is that once you scroll down to a certain point, the first background image gets cut off (as it should) but the second background image scrolls too soon and leaves this "whitespace" where the background is revealed. I will give a jsfiddle link so you can see what I am talking about. You might have to expand the viewport on jsfiddle to see the first background image for some reason. Thanks in advance.

CSS:

```
    body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: rgb(114, 129, 139);
  overflow-x: hidden;
  animation: fadein 1s;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
h1 {
  line-height: 300px;
  font-size: 90px;
  font-family: "Avant Garde", Avantgarde, "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic,
  "AppleGothic", sans-serif;
}
h2 {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 50px;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-family: "Avant Garde", Avantgarde, "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic,
  "AppleGothic", sans-serif;
}
#p_in_first_div {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 120px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-family: "Avant Garde", Avantgarde, "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic,
  "AppleGothic", sans-serif;
}
#first_bg_image {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
#first_bg_image::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0;
  bottom: 0; left: 0;
  background: url(http://pngimg.com/uploads/businessman/businessman_PNG6580.png);
  background-position: 49em 0px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  margin-top: -1700px;
  width: 120%;
  height: 3100px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  pointer-events: none;
  transform: scale(.80);
}
#second_bg_image {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
#second_bg_image::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0;
  bottom: 0; left: 0;
  background: url(https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/desktop-with-notebook-smartphone-coffee-and-laptop_1112-253.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  margin-top: 377px;
  height: 1600px;
  background-position: center;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0.7;
  transform: scale(1, 0.8);
}
#header_div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 40px;
  background-color: rgb(143, 0, 46);
}
#header_nav {
  line-height: 70px;
  word-spacing: 25px;
  font-size: 13.4px;
}
#header_div_icon {
  position: relative;
  right: 50px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}
#current_link_home {
  color: rgb(190, 226, 231);
}
#first_body_div {
  height: 690px;
  width: 820px;
  background-color: rgb(69, 72, 87);
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 15%;
  margin-bottom: 7%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 30px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: relative;
}
#icon_in_div {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 160px 0px 0px 0px;
}
#resume_button {
  background-color: Transparent;
  border: 2px solid rgb(79, 87, 170);
  outline: none;
  font-family: "Avant Garde", Avantgarde, "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic,
  "AppleGothic", sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  line-height: 45px;
  width: 220px;
  height: 45px;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}
#professional_skills_div_1 {
  width: 230px;
  height: 15px;;
  background-color: rgb(79, 87, 170);
}
#professional_skills_div_2 {
  width: 230px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: rgb(79, 87, 170);
}
#professional_skills_div_3 {
  width: 230px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: rgb(79, 87, 170);
}
#professional_skills_div_4 {
  width: 430px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: rgb(79, 87, 170);
}
#professional_skills_div_5 {
  width: 280px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: rgb(79, 87, 170);
}
#professional_skills_div_6 {
  width: 480px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: rgb(79, 87, 170);
}
#professional_skills_div_7 {
  width: 480px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: rgb(79, 87, 170);
}
#professional_skill_percentage_80 {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  right: -20px;
  top: -4px;
}
#professional_skill_percentage_60 {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  right: 130px;
  top: -3px;
}
.h2_line_heights {
  line-height: 450px;
}
.other_links {
  color: rgb(114, 129, 139);
}
.text_align {
  text-align: center;
}
.text_color {
  color: rgb(190, 226, 231);
}
.h2_subheadings_font {
  font-size: 30px;
}
.h2_subheadings_positions {
  position: relative;
  top: -260px;
}
.professional_divs {
  position: relative;
  right: 32px;
  height: 45px;
  top: -210px;
  width: 1400px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.professional_outside_divs {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 35%;
}
.professional_paragraphs {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  text-align: right;
  position: relative;
  right: 40px;
  top: -4px;
}
.professional_outside_skill_bar_divs {
  width: 29%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  right: 1.5vw;
}
.professional_skill_percentages_50 {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  right: 180px;
  top: -4px;
}
.professional_skill_percentage_90 {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  left: 70px;
  top: -3px;
}
```

HTML:

```
    <body lang="en-US">
  <div id="first_bg_image">
  <header>
    <div id="header_div">
      <nav class="text_align" id="header_nav">
        <!--
        image source:
        https://scrapbookalphabet.blogspot.com/2011/08/wood-slat-png-free-scrapbook-letters.html?m=1
        -->
        <img id="header_div_icon"
        src="https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-8Gdu_oKhrdM/Tk_5-lBzZII/AAAAAAAACIU/cw3CLnAXv5k/s1600/1Capital-Letter-C-Wood.png"
        alt="Icon 1">
        <a href="#" id="current_link_home">HOME</a>
        <a href="#prof_id" class="other_links" id="professional_link">
          PROFESSIONAL
        </a>
        <a href="#exper_id" class="other_links" id="experience_link">
          EXPERIENCE
        </a>
        <a href="portfolio_page.html" class="other_links" id="portfolio_link">
          PORTFOLIO
        </a>
        <a href="#second_body_div" class="other_links" id="contact_link">
          CONTACT
        </a>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="text_align">
    <h1 class="text_color">
      I<span>'</span>m Chad Wilson<span>.</span>
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="text_align">
    <h2 class="text_color h2_subheadings_font">
      Front End Web Developer
    </h2>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="second_bg_image">
  <div id="first_body_div">
    <img id="icon_in_div"
    src="https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-8Gdu_oKhrdM/Tk_5-lBzZII/AAAAAAAACIU/cw3CLnAXv5k/s1600/1Capital-Letter-C-Wood.png"
    alt="Icon 2">
    <p class="text_align text_color" id="p_in_first_div">
      Click the link below to download my resume.
    </p>
    <a href="https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5NM_iPTWudsRzRzS094Ul9pMTQ/view?usp=sharing"
    id="resume_button"
    class="text_color text_align"
    target="_blank">
      Download Resume
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="text_align h2_line_heights" id="prof_id">
    <h2 class="text_color">
      <span>01</span> Professional
    </h2>
  </div>
  <div class="text_align">
    <h2 class="text_color h2_subheadings_font h2_subheadings_positions">
      My Knowledge Level in Software
    </h2>
  </div>
  <div class="professional_divs">
    <div class="professional_outside_divs">
      <p class="professional_paragraphs text_color">
        Wordpress
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="professional_outside_skill_bar_divs">
      <div id="professional_skills_div_1">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="professional_outside_divs">
      <p class="professional_skill_percentages_50 text_color">
        50%
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="professional_divs">
    <div class="professional_outside_divs">
      <p class="professional_paragraphs text_color">
        Drupal
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="professional_outside_skill_bar_divs">
      <div id="professional_skills_div_2">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="professional_outside_divs">
      <p class="professional_skill_percentages_50 text_color">
        50%
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="professional_divs">
    <div class="professional_outside_divs">
      <p class="professional_paragraphs text_color">
        Wix
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="professional_outside_skill_bar_divs">
      <div id="professional_skills_div_3">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="professional_outside_divs">
      <p class="professional_skill_percentages_50 text_color">
        50%
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="professional_divs remove_bottom_bar">
    <div class="professional_outside_divs">
      <p class="professional_paragraphs text_color">
        Photoshop
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="professional_outside_skill_bar_divs">
      <div id="professional_skills_div_4">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="professional_outside_divs">
      <p class="text_color" id="professional_skill_percentage_80">
        80%
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="professional_divs">
    <div class="professional_outside_divs">
      <p class="professional_paragraphs text_color">
        Illustrator
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="professional_outside_skill_bar_divs">
      <div id="professional_skills_div_5">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="professional_outside_divs">
      <p class="text_color" id="professional_skill_percentage_60">
        60%
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="professional_divs remove_bottom_bar">
    <div class="professional_outside_divs">
      <p class="professional_paragraphs text_color">
        Javascript
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="professional_outside_skill_bar_divs">
      <div id="professional_skills_div_6">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="professional_outside_divs">
      <p class="text_color professional_skill_percentage_90">
        90%
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="professional_divs remove_bottom_bar">
    <div class="professional_outside_divs">
      <p class="professional_paragraphs text_color">
        HTML & CSS
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="professional_outside_skill_bar_divs">
      <div id="professional_skills_div_7">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="professional_outside_divs">
      <p class="text_color professional_skill_percentage_90">
        90%
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JSFIDDLE link: https://jsfiddle.net/245uqz0p/

Answer (score 0):

I think this link might help you.

[w3school parallax effect](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_parallax.asp)